# is a Solution in SSMS worthwhile?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I've been wrestling with the SSMS Solution in SQL 2008. I'm beginning to wonder if other professionals actually use this feature -- it just seems like it doesn't work well. Opinions? Avoid like the plague? Suggestions for using it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use solutions in SSMS. This is probably because I use Visual Studio Database Edition for all our database schema management and have no real need to create SSMS solutions. I did try them a couple times with SQL Server 2005 and found them fickle. I never saw any real benefit.